# How to get currently executed file directory in CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to check some site and write JSON data into a file. File should be written into `public/data` folder. But when I'm trying to call `casperjs`  outside of my project directory (e.g. my home directory), it writes file directly in `~/public/data`, not in my project directory.

How should I solve this? I haven't found how to get __dirname or __filename.

Comment: Do you have example code you've been working with?

Comment: Hello, InviS. Has this been answered sufficiently? Could you be so kind as to mark an answer on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

I had this exact issue; requiring a file in a path relative to where the script lived.
With a little (read: a lot of) tinkering, I was able to produce the following:

```js
// Since Casper has control, the invoked script is deep in the argument stack
const args = require('system').args;
var currentFile = args[args.length - 1];
var curFilePath = fs.absolute(currentFile).split('/');

// I only bother to change the directory if we weren't already there when invoking casperjs
if (curFilePath.length > 1) {
    curFilePath.pop(); // PhantomJS does not have an equivalent path.baseName()-like method
    fs.changeWorkingDirectory(curFilePath.join('/'));
}
```

This allows me to `fs.read()` and `spawn` files using relative paths. Perhaps `require()` as well, I just didn't have a module to test it with.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Didn't knew about `require('system').args`

Comment: This obviously requires `var fs = require('fs');`

Answer (score 2):

You can use FileSystem module of phantomJS.

Because CasperJS was built over PhantomJS, you can include Phantom's modules inside your CasperJS Scripts.

Try:

```js
//require a reference to the fs module
var fs = require('fs');
...
//changes the current workingDirectory to the specified path.
fs.changeWorkingDirectory('/your/path')
```

Full documentation about FileSystem Module [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/)

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
var system = require('system')
var absoluteFilePath = system.args[4];
var absoluteFileDir = absoluteFilePath.replace('{your_file_name}', '');
```

To check system args:

```
console.log(system.args)
```

Answer (score 1):

All that you need is to use [phantomjs fs](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/property/working-directory.html):

Basically you can set on your project as full path:

```
var fs = require('fs');
console.log(fs.workingDirectory);
// output "F:/path/to/your/project"
```

Answer (score 0):

You give an answer for a specific casperjs call with 4 arguments.
The general solution is to take the last argument as absoluteFilePath

```
var system = require('system')
var absoluteFilePath = system.args[system.args.length-1];
var absoluteFileDir = absoluteFilePath.replace('{your_file_name}', '');
```

Comment: In my setting, I don't see that absoluteFilePath is the last index in system.args. On the contrary, it seems to me the 4th element